# Mean and S.D of Normal distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, mean

A random variable X follows a normal distribution with mean = 5 and standard deviation = 25. Find mean and standard deviation of 5X?

What I did: 5E[X] = 5*5 = 25

Variance: 25*25 = 625

Var(5X) = 25Var(X) = 625*25 = 15625 
Therefore S.D = 125.

Isn't it so? Or there is another way for normal distribution?

Comment: $Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ is the right formula.

Comment: Oh yes. I will correct it. Is my mean correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @user2974951 in the above equation that you have given, the second part: E[X]2 = 625? I'm getting stuck on the first part.

Comment: $E[X^2]$ is the second moment of your distribution, which is trivial to compute for the normal distribution, Wikipedia has the formula for it.

Comment: Your calculations are correct and they would be correct even if the question was not about a normal distribution.  No matter what the distribution of $X$ is, as long as $X$ has a mean and variance, it is true that $E[aX]=aE[X]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$

Comment: @user2974951 It would be have been far better if you had actually _looked_ at the formula in Wikipedia instead of just referring to it; it would have told you that $E[X^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X) +(E[X])^2 = \sigma^2+(E[X])^2$ where we are _given_ that $\sigma=5$ and so we know what the value of the variance is. It is totally unnecessary to first find $E[X^2]$ by adding $(E[X])^2$ to the variance of $X$, and then find the variance of $X$ by subtracting off $(E[X])^2$ from $E[X^2]$.

Comment: Your method looks OK: Reality check with simulation in R: `set.seed(523);`
`x = rnorm(10^6, 5, 25);  y = 5*x;` `mean(x); sd(x)` returns 4.990017 and 25.01431 (close to 5 and 25) and `mean(y);  /sd(y)` returns 24.95008 and 125.0715 (close to 25 and 125). // Sometimes $Var(X) = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ is useful; as @DilipSarwate Comments, not needed here.